# Passing Data through Promise Chain (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

The question is hard to describe so let me post an example.
The context is AngularJS `$q`, but any solutions based on ES6 `Promise` are also welcome.

Suppose we want to cancel an `$http` request. In AngularJS this is implemented by providing a promise A to `$http.get()` method. Resolve promise A will result in cancelling the request. So the code will look like this:

```
function httpCall() {
    const promiseA = $q.defer();
    const promiseB = $http.get(url, { timeout: promiseA.promise });
    return promiseB;
}
```

In order to return `promiseA` so that the caller of `httpCall` can cancel the request, the only way I found is to assign it to `promiseB`, like this:

```
function httpCall() {
    const promiseA = $q.defer();
    let promiseB = $http.get(url, { timeout: promiseA });
    promiseB.canceller = promiseA;
    return promiseB;
}
```

The problem is, `promiseB` may be passed through a long promise chain (such as action dispatch, mapping, other post-processes), for example:

```
function doSomeAction() {
    return httpCall()
        .then((response) => {
            processResponse(response);
            return response;
        });
}
```

Obviously, the return value of `doSomeAction` is NOT the same promise as the origin promise `promiseB`.

Thus if I have a function who calls `doSomeAction()`, this function will not be able to retrieve `promiseB` (it can only get the return promise of `doSomeAction()`), thus not able to cancel the request.

Someone may say we can pass the data (`promiseA`) through the chain. However I consider the existance of `promiseA` should be transparent to the chain itself, i.e. the functions in the chain should never know the existance of `promiseA`. Thus I cannot depend on the chain to pass data for me.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The `timeout` property of the $http config should be a promise. The variable `promiseA` is not a promise object; it is a deferred. A promise object is `$q.deferred().promise`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing about `promiseA` makes total sense as things are happening on the different levels of abstraction. `doSomeAction` abstracts out http call and providing any API which cancels underlying http call breaks an abstraction and reveal `doSomeAction`'s implementation details. Instead I would think about making `doSomeAction` cancellable i.e. providing a `cancel` method on an object it returns. This cancel method can cancel underlying http request (or several of them if there are several) or skip cancelling if no http request was made and data was taken from local storage or do whatever makes sense for `doSomeAction`, not just particular http request which is just part of a bigger picture on this layer.

Comment: That totally makes sense when considering the chain may be complicated (e.g. `$q.all()`). While I'm still trying to find out how to make it generic, I'll take this as the last solution. Thank you @nutic